# How to add scripts to wordpress media screen

Tags: wordpress

I have to add a drag and drop feature on wordpress media screen : wp-admin/upload.php

```
class myClass extends Config {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'callback_admin_enqueue_scripts'] );
    }
    // Enqueue scripts
    public function callback_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
                wp_register_script('myscript', MY_BASE_URL  . '/scripts/my-script.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-droppable','jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-sortable'), '1.0' );

    }
}
```

And later from my-script.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    // Where .attachment.save-ready is a class of each attachment
    console.log(jQuery('.attachment.save-ready'));
    
});
```

[image: attachment class attributes form wordpress media screen]

And the result from the console is just null, seems the attachment is loaded after my script.

Someone has already seen similar issue? what is the recommended way to append scripts to worpdress media screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you face script loading issue then you can also use setTimeout function to call script after 2 sec once DOM ready.

Comment: true but not an efficient solution.